# Trying to generate fibonacci spiral but getting a black image instead,stuck up

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I was trying to generate the Fibonacci spiral through open-cv but getting a black image instead.Im stuck up and dont know if the approach is correct

```
import cv2,numpy as np,itertools as i
from math import sqrt
a,b=[6600,5100]  
s,f=[np.ones((b,a,3),np.uint8),lambda n: ((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1- 
sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*sqrt(5))[0]]
for r,c in i.product(range(b),range(a)):
    s[r,c]=[math.sin(f(5)*255)]
cv2.imwrite("out.png",s)
```

Expecting a Fibonaci spiral in colours